# EF Core 2.2 navigational property creating a duplicate entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.2

For an **existing Blog** entity I'm adding a **new Post** with B**log as a navigational property**. The error is that a **duplicate Blog** is being inserted. Using **EF Core 2.2**

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId);
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

PostFactory.cs

```
  public Post CreateNew(Guid id)
    {
        var post = new Post(id);

        return post;
    }
```

PostService.cs

```
   public Post Create(Guid blogId)
    {
        var blog = _context.Blogs.Include(t=>t.Posts).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == blogId);

        var postFactory = new PostFactory();
        var post = postFactory.CreateNew(Guid.NewGuid());

        post.Blog = blog;
        post.BlogId = blogId;

        blog.Posts.Add(post);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return post;
    }
```

Not sure why an existing Blog is again trying to be inserted into the DB. I get an error:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Blogs'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Blogs'

Comment: I belive because you configure it to have the foreign key as BlogForeignKey but then when you set it you set the BlogId. BlogId should be the foreign key in my opinion

Comment: Thank you, I've edited it to blogId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either assign blogId in the post OR add  the post to the blog, I believe doing both can give you unexpected results, try this :

```
public Post Create(Guid blogId)
{
    var blog = _context.Blogs.Include(t=>t.Posts).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == blogId);

    var postFactory = new PostFactory();
    var post = postFactory.CreateNew(Guid.NewGuid());

    blog.Posts.Add(post);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return post;
}
```

Comment: Could you please let me know which one to assign, blog or blogId?

Comment: Normally I would assign blogId, just to keep it simple. This approach should work as well since on SaveChanges() the blog will be updated and will include the new Post

Comment: None, just by adding the post to blog entity should be enough: blog.Posts.Add(post);